# How to consume a web API which is deployed on Docker desktop client?

Tags: docker, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, port

I am self learning .Net core and docker.

I have developed an .Net core API prototype that is deployed on docker desktop client running on my machine and I want to consume it in a desktop application.

Below mentioned code trying to consume the API is giving and error:

> Unable to connect to the server

```
Dim request As WebRequest =  WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:54382/weather")
Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
```

I guess the issue is with the port number. I am using the port shown on the docker client against the application running.

I want a generic fix that would work with docker desktop client and also when the app is deployed on docker hub.

Comment: How are you running the docker container?

Comment: On Visual Studio, Docker option on the toolbar to run. On docker client, dashboard I can see that the application is running.

Answer (score 0):

There are two separate networks. Inside docker is one network. Outside docker, on the host machine, it's another network. If you are accessing it by localhost or IP address it won't work as you are expecting it. You'll have to cross the network boundary and get into the host machine boundary. Or you'll have to tell docker network how to resolve the special localhost. Run this command you'll get some idea about docker networking:

`docker network ls`

You should see a very similar output:

```
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
58a4dd9893e9        133_default         bridge              local
424817227b42        bridge              bridge              local
739297b8107e        host                host                local
b9c4fb3ed4ba        none                null                local
```

You need to add the host for service on localhost. Try running like a below command:

`docker run --add-host myservice:<ip address of host computer> <your image>`

Hopefully, this will fix it.

More here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#managing-etchosts